# body onload not working in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am using

```
<body marginheight='0' topmargin='0' leftmargin='0' onLoad='setFocus()'>
```

and in javascript I am using

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
function setFocus(){
  alert("Hello");
document.frm.txtName.focus()
} 
</script>
```

this is not working in IE but working perfectly in FF and chrome browsers

any idea please?

Comment: Try using it with lowercase `onload`

Comment: Hi Niels thanks for your response I tried this but still not working. Its still give me SCRIPT5009: 'setFocus' is undefined  error

Comment: No.Its not reaching inside the setFocus() method

Comment: Its inside body tag just below where head tag ends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `document.frm.txtName.focus()` to `document.forms[0].txtName.focus()`. This will work in IE.

Make shure that your `<form name="frm">` is the first form on page. I.e: before this form shuldn't be any other `<form>` elements in document.

If you can't do that just add the `id` attribute to the your `txtName` text field. For example :

```
<input type="text" name="txtName" id="someId">
```

And in your function `setFocus` write:

```
function setFocus(){
   document.getElementById('someId').focus()
}
```

Comment: I tried it but its not even reaching inside setFocus() method. Its saying  SCRIPT5009: 'setFocus' is undefined when I check console

Comment: Its inside body tag just below where head tag ends

Comment: put the setFocus script in the <head>, reference it in the onload.

Answer (score -1):

Try `window.onload`, it will work man.